# how do I use expect along with a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I have a text file with a bunch of operations that i would like to send using my expect script which looks like (replacing op1 & op2 with the commands in my textr file, one command per line):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh root@ccTest telnet jpaxdp
expect {\-> }
send "op1(20)\r"
expect {\-> }
send "op2\r"
expect {\-> }
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I understand your question. It seems to me the easiest thing to do is to let expect handle reading the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set command_file [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ssh root@ccTest telnet jpaxdp
expect {\-> }

set fh [open $command_file r]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    send "$line\r"
    expect {\-> }
}
close $fh

send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Then

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know `expect` would eat script commands like this! Works great! Thanks!

Comment: Expect extends Tcl which is a general purpose language. There's not much it can't do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash script to create a sequence of commands for expect and send them to it.

For example you have `cmds.txt`:

```
echo hello
echo goodbye
```

And following bash script named `ex.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'spawn bash'
while read line; do
    echo 'expect {$ }'
    echo send '"'"$line\r"'"'
done
echo 'expect {$ }'
echo 'send "exit\r"'
echo 'expect eof'
```

So now all you have to do is use pipelines like that:

```
cat cmds.txt | bash ex.sh | expect
```

It outputs:

```
admin@admin:/tmp$ cat cmds.txt | bash ex.sh | expect 
spawn bash
admin@admin:/tmp$ echo hello
hello
admin@admin:/tmp$ echo goodbuy
goodbuy
admin@admin:/tmp$ exit
exit
```

Comment: frist, but how does this work with my telnet connection on the remote ssh host, see the `spawn` line in my script above:`spawn ssh root@ccTest telnet jpaxdp`

Comment: @cerr This should works because of pseudo-tty which except emulates. I hope if you have key-based ssh authentication this should works. What kind of problems do you have? If there any problem with ssh try to add -t option to ssh